# jQuery each element in document

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I wrote a code that changes the size of each textarea(which has autosize class) in the document. It works ok:

```
$(document).each('textarea.autosize', function(){

   $(this).attr("style", "height:" + (this.scrollHeight) + "px; overflow-y:hidden;");

}).on("input", function(){

   this.style.height = "auto";

   this.style.height = (this.scrollHeight) + "px";

});
```

But my web page contents are dynamic. for click event I can do this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.myClass', function(){});
```

But for `each` I can't.
How can I use `each` for elements that they are not in the DOM yet?

Comment: You should apply attributes at the time of element creation/insertion, not insert an element, then detect that insertion and finally apply needed attributes. For events, it is sufficient to add an event listener to a common parent element and then filter cases in handler.

Comment: Instead of using `.attr()` you can set the style via [`.css()`](https://api.jquery.com/css/) and pass an object to avoid string concatination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the autosize functionality in a function that you can call when you add elements to the DOM:

```js
function autosize() {
    $(document).each('textarea.autosize', function() {
       $(this).attr("style", "height:" + (this.scrollHeight) + "px; overflow-y:hidden;");
    }).on("input", function(){

       this.style.height = "auto";

       this.style.height = (this.scrollHeight) + "px";

    });
}

autosize();
```

If you add elements, you can do:

```js
$('.add').click(function() {
    $(document).append($('<textarea />', { class: 'autosize' }));
    autosize();
});
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to add this everywhere you add something:

```js
setInverval(autosize, 100);
```

**Caution:** This solution is considered bad for your performance! So consider using one of my other solutions.

If you only want to do this, when actually an element is added, you can listen this via [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver):

```js
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    var elements = [ ...mutation.addedNodes].filter((node) => node.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'textarea' && node.classList.contains('.autosize'));
    if (elements.length) {
        autosize();
    }
});

observer.observe(document, {attributes: false, childList: true, characterData: false, subtree:true});
```

It might be better for your performance to not query already modified elements again (as pointed out in the comments):

```js
$(document).each('textarea.autosize', autosize).on("input", resize);
function autosize() {function() {
   $(this).attr("style", "height:" + (this.scrollHeight) + "px; overflow-y:hidden;");
}

function resize() {
   this.style.height = "auto";

   this.style.height = (this.scrollHeight) + "px";
}

autosize();
```

In this case you have to run both `autosize()` and `resize()` when a new element is added.

Comment: Why on earth would it be necessary to query and modify all the already existing elements every time a new one is added? And `setInterval`? Really? This is probably the worst performant code I've ever seen. OP has to add element attributes at element creation time and handle events with a single listener, end of story.

Comment: `setInterval()` was meant to be only a fallback option if the OP doesn't like any of the other for whatever reason but I'll add your hint to it to make that more clear.

Comment: Actually all the proposed solutions are bad for performance. DOM elements querying is an expensive operation and should be avoided when possible. `setInterval` just made things worse by repeating that expensive operation at an insanely fast rate. The problem with `MutationObserver` is that you are using it at the root of the document with the `subtree` property and it can be very, very expensive too. All of this can be avoided if attributes and events related stuff is added to each new element before being added to the DOM.

Comment: SO is not a code review platform so I primarily try to solve questions in the scope given by the TO. Nonetheless, I added a solution that doesn't involve querying already modified elements.

Comment: You're welcome. Please read @ErnestoStifano's comments on performance. They might be helpful to you.